# Is there a working Xtree or equivalent for 20.04 LTS?

Tags: software-recommendation, kde, tree

There are times when I want the capabilities of xtree, unixtree, etc., that shows a "graphical" display of a directory hierarchy.  I have installed KDE dolphin that more or less has this functionality, but not nearly as compact as xtree. I have used the CLI command tree; the functionality of tree is too limited. Is there a working xtree, etc., available for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?  If the installation of a xtree-like application requires additional files/utilities and apt does not automatically get these or if the installation is outside of the apt utilities, please indicate (or provide a link to) what additional steps/configurations are needed.

Comment: You can try some of these applications: Midnight Commander, Double Commander, WCM Commander, Sunflower Manager,

Comment: https://net2.com/how-to-install-sunflower-file-manager-on-ubuntu-20-04/  Sunflower Manager is pre-production (beta) release 0.4.62-2 .  I prefer production releases although I have installed Sunflower that does not appear to have a tree view --  I have posted to the non-Ubuntu Sunflower list the question of a tree view.  Any further recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The file manager [**ytree**](https://www.han.de/%7Ewerner/ytree.html) is almost identical to *xtree*. Also you can look at the [Xtree Fan Page](http://www.xtreefanpage.org/) for other clones. EDIT: In that page, [**unixtree**](https://unixtree.org) is the more mature and feature filled clone.

Comment: sudo apt install unixtree
[sudo] password for ykarant: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unixtree   However,   ytree is installable using apt; I did so, but ytree fails with internal errors.  Screenshot of the failure is available -- how do I attach it to this comment?